# Регулярное выражение захватывает слишком много текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть HTML

```
<table>
....
<!--ID 25--></table>

<table>
....
<!--ID 26--></table>
```

Регулярка

```
<table>(.*)<!--ID [0-9]{0,4}--></table>
```

возвращает полностью код, содержащий 2 таблицы сразу.
Как запросить, чтобы регулярка вернула каждую таблицу по отдельности?

Comment: Может быть, не каждую таблицу по отдельности, а одну таблицу? Второй регуляркой - вторую таблицу?

Comment: @Алексей Дорохов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Надо уменьшить жадность квантификатора, то есть заменить `*` ("жадная" версия) `*?` ("ленивой" версией). Вот так:

```
<table>(.*?)<!--ID [0-9]{0,4}--><\/table>
         ^^
```

Или (если библиотека регулярных выражений не поддерживает модификатор `DOTALL`)

```
<table>([\s\S]*?)<!--ID [0-9]{0,4}--><\/table>
        ^^^^^^^^
```

**[Посмотреть пример работы](http://regex101.com/r/wC4oI9/3)**