# Как удалить,или заменить несколько похожих текста содержащих спецсимволы?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст:

```
$text = "AAAA text
<h1>aaa</h1>
Любой текст 
[mt5]({is_hedged})[/mt5] Любой текст [mt5]({is_hedged})[/mt5]
BBBtext
AAAA text
[mt5]({is_hedged})[/mt5] 
Любой текст 
BBBtext";
```

Хочу удалить все такие строки `[mt5]({is_hedged})[/mt5]`по этому выражению:

```
$text = preg_replace('#[mt5].*[/mt5]#s', '', $text);
echo($text);
```

Бесполезно.Удаляет между первым `[mt5]` и вторым `[/mt5]`

Как  написать правильно ?

Спасибо !

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение захватывает слишком много текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359258/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Это не дубликат потому что  вопрос как удалить,заменить  а не найти.Впредь читайте внимательней вопросы а потом минусуйте, или отмечайте дубликатами.

Comment: Это дубликат, потому что решение - ленивая версия квантификатора (`.*` => `.*?`). И всё решится само собой. Таких вопросов миллион по всей сети.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Если я ту регулярку помещу в свою `preg_replace` , интересно решится ли мой вопрос ,или вы не вдаетесь в подробности ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Раз вы уже поняли что ошиблись то пожалуйста отмените свой минус.Все мы ошибаемся,.Нет там ничего постыдного.Стыдно тогда когда не хотим исправить ее

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Не знаю, может это и дупликат, но если не знать, в чём дело, тот вопрос едва ли получится найти. Это и объясняет «миллион вопросов». И в самой первой версии ещё были неэкранированные скобки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Экранировать квадратные скобки и сделать [ленивый квантификатор](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.repetition.php).

```
$text = preg_replace('#\[mt5\].*?\[/mt5\]#s', '', $text);
```

Comment: Упс не заработало регулярка))). Можете здесь тестировать http://regexr.com/

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan наверное из-за того, что там регулярные выражения внутри `/`, а не `#`?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, упс, а у меня вот эта регулярка отлично работает в отличии от вашей.

Comment: @Visman точно скопируйте и посмотрите работает или синтаксис не правильный?

Comment: @Visman Здесь проверьте http://regexr.com/

Comment: @Visman Здесь синтаксическая ошибка `'#\[mt5\].*?\[/mt5\]#s'`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, покажите мне эту синтаксическую ошибку. Я вижу правильное регулярное выражение.

Comment: @Visman Вот смотрите на скриншот, не знаю какая у вас версия `PHP` но оно точно везде не будет работать. линк - `https://ibb.co/ffKjtF`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan в моём регулярном выражении и в вашем используются разные [разделители](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: @pocketgulag Разделители не как не влияют на правильный синтаксис написания регулярки, можете еще раз посмотреть скриншот.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan цитирую из документации по ссылке выше: «Если необходимо использовать разделитель внутри шаблона, его нужно проэкранировать с помощью обратной косой черты». А если используется не разделитель (и не другой специальный символ), то его не нужно экранировать, очевидно.

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите восстановить правду: 
Мой вопрос безосновательно помечен дупликатом и  минусован.
Ту ссылку которая приводится в качестве доказательства не решает мою проблему + это по сути другой вопрос,о выборке а не удаление или  замене. 
Спасибо !

Comment: @pocketgulag А это по твоему работающая ? смотри на скриншот - https://ibb.co/dYk7DF

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan второй блок не совпадает, так как нет модификатора `g`. Думаю, захватывать всё до последнего закрывающего элемента нет необходимости, но все равно, наверное, такое выражение: `/\[mt5\].*?\[\/mt5\](?=(?:(?!\[\/mt5\]).)*(?:\[mt5\]|$))/gm` сможет это сделать. В вашем же выражении нельзя использовать символ `[` внутри блока.

Comment: @pocketgulag Я не помнил но так как сказал `Visman` модификатор `g` нет в `PHP`

Comment: @pocketgulag А взять до последнего `[/mt5]` необходимо

Answer (score 2):

Квадратные скобки нужно экранировать

Comment: Где вы в вопросе увидели не экранированные скобки?

Comment: Не рабочий вариант,извините

Comment: @Visman, в первой редакции, например :-)

Comment: @Visman, т. е. в принятом ответе тебя они не смущают?

Comment: @Qwertiy, 1. я уже заметил первую правку до вашего комментария и удалил свой вопрос на мете (тоже до вашего комментария). 2. Принятый ответ дан после первой правки, когда скобки были экранированы. 3. ГЛАВНОЕ. Автор в вопросе ясно пишет `Удаляет между первым [mt5] и вторым [/mt5]`, то есть регулярка у него работала изначально, но не верно. Отсюда делаю вывод: не экранированные скобки в его вопросе это описка.

Answer (score 2):

Замените жадное `.*` на ленивое `.*?`.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\[mt5\].*\[\/mt5\]/', '', $text);
```

**UPD**

В случае если паттерн встречается в одной строке:

```
preg_replace('/\[mt5\].*?\[\/mt5\]/', '', $text);
```

Comment: `..... [mt5]({is_hedged})[/mt5] aklshdjdhfjkasdhf [mt5]({is_hedged})[/mt5]....`  когда встречаются на одной строке то удаляет неправильно

Comment: Замените жадное .* на ленивое .*? как советует @Visman

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer А если текст будет таким то что сделает ваша регулярка?
`[mt5] ({is_hedged})[/mt5]  сдфдсфдсфдсфдсф [mt5] ({is_hedged})[/mt5]`

Comment: Второй пример подходит с `s` в конце.Потому Что без `s` каждая строка  обрабатывается отдельно

Answer (score 0):

Можешь сделать так:))))

```
$text = preg_replace('#(\[mt5\])([^\[]*)(\[\/mt5\])#', '', $text);
echo($text);
```

Comment: Тоже рабочий вариант ,но к сожалению запоздалый

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Да конечно, но как то не понятно вот с этой, как работает если в нем и ошибка есть? `'#\[mt5\].*?\[/mt5\]#s'`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, этот вариант перестает быть рабочим, если у вас между нужными тегами встретится квадратная скобка.

Comment: @Visman А вот мой вариант когда между нужными тегами квадратная скобка - link - https://ibb.co/kVcXfv

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, кривая работа вашей регулярки https://regex101.com/r/TLOzFi/1 + в preg_replace() нет флага `g`.

Comment: @Visman правильно, это не учел, поправлю ответ.