# Регулярное выражение выбирает больше чем нужно

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка.
логин;пароль | логин;пароль

```
Mwrqpdcm@mail.ru;MmsywergNkjvukgd | Hoixjxol@mail.ru;Psgbmffh
```

Я хочу с помощью регулярки, выбрать первый логин, пытаюсь так:

```
.*;
```

. - любой символ

*-от 0 до бесконечности

; - до точки с запятой чтобы выбрало

Хочу получить  **Mwrqpdcm@mail.ru**

Но эта регулярка выбирает весь текст до второй точки с запятой...

Почему так?

Comment: сделайте менее жадным `.*?;`  или явно `[^;]*;`

Comment: Online regex tester, debugger with highlighting for PHP, PCRE, Python, Golang and JavaScript. https://regex101.com/   *Нежадный - находит минимальную строку, удовлетворяющую условию.
Жадный - максимальную.

Comment: что-нибудь такое, первая группа логин, вторая пароль [ |]{0,3}([^;]+);([^ ]+)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение захватывает слишком много текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359258/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Хотя тут и регулярное выражение не нужно, используйте `explode(';', $text)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать нежадный режим захвата: `.*?;`.