# Регулярное выражение захват всех цифр

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Шаблон - `/<sip:.*(\d+)/`

Искомая строка - `<sip:+373123456789@user=phone>`

Почему захватывается только последняя цифра?

Comment: `/(?<=sip[^\d]+\+)[^@]+/` или `/sip[^\d]+\+\K[^@]+/`

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [Регулярное выражение захватывает слишком много текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359258/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему захватывается только последняя цифра?

Потому что квантификатор `*` по-умолчанию жадный (greedy) - он заставляет токен `.` матчить максимально возможное количество символов (числовые к `.` тоже подходят).

Есть два варианта решения:

- сделать квантификатор ленивым (lazy), `/<sip:.*?(\d+)/`
- использовать токен нечисловых символов, например `/<sip:\D*(\d+)/`

Comment: Вот второй вариант как раз подходит, как раз именно на таком и я остановился

Comment: @quaresma89, Еще можно `[^\d]*`, но `\D*` по идее должен быстрее работать :) Еще, может поддерживаться флаг-модификатор `U` который делает квантификаторы ленивыми по-умолчанию, но тогда придется поменять жадность плюса: `(\d+?)`. Вопросительный знак после квантификатора это инверсия жадности, если я ничего не путаю.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что .* означает любое количество символов - оно и съедает плюсик и весь номер кроме последней цифры, которая попадает под (\d+)
Можно написать так

```
/<sip:\+(\d+)/
```

тогда захватывается весь номер, но нужно что бы плюс обязательно присутствовал. 
Еще вариант -
 `/<sip:.*(\d{12})/` 
захватит ровно 12 цифр вне зависимости от наличия плюса.

Comment: Как вариант, но лучше \d+ так как длина может варироваться

Comment: А если так попробовать? /sip\D*(\d+)@/. То есть после sip может быть или нет любой символ не нумерический, а далее уже цифры любое кол-во раз

Comment: Да, так будет еще лучше.