# Как в регулярке захватить все что находится до первого символа?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

вот допустим пример

> 'этот текст мне нужен / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст
> / текст / текст /

На месте "текст" может быть сколько угодно слов, и какие угодно символы кроме /

Мне надо захватить все что находится до первого символа /, как это сделать? Пробовал так (.+)\s/ но это захватывает все до последнего символа / а мне нужно до первого

Comment: почитайте про [квантификацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)) - `(.+?)\s/`

Comment: `^[^\/]+` все кроме `/`

Comment: @Smorvel это уже другой вопрос. Задайте его так же, как и первый, а тут примите один из ответов, если они решили вопрос, с помощью галки слева

Comment: @Smorvel можно использовать примерно такую регулярку: `(?<=\s\/\s)([^\s]+)`

Comment: @Smorvel так вам текущие решения не подошли? Объясните, почему тогда

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение захватывает слишком много текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359258/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
^[^/]*
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5ak3c

> **'этот текст мне нужен** / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст /

Comment: Я насчёт пробела не уверен.

Comment: @Qwertiy в плане надо ли его захватывать? Ну в условии сказано "надо захватить **все** что находится до первого символа", поэтому захватываю его тоже

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.+?)\/
```

***^*** указывает на начало строки.Скобки на то, что надо захватить часть в скобках и проигнорировать первую встреченную косую черту,потом эту группу захваченных символов надо будет извлечь.

Предлагаю вам прочитать про жадные и ленивые квантификаторы в регулярных выражениях.Очень пригодится и поймете что тут значит комбинация **'+?'**.

Пример выполнения: regexr.com/5am2c

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочется возиться с регулярками, то можно использовать обычный split, мне кажется это легче:

```
var = '/test/asd/123/'
print(var.split('/')[1])
# test
```

Адаптируется под любой язык

Comment: @Smorvel На каком языке программа?

Comment: @Smorvel не получится с помощью регулярных выражений в JS получить именно эту строку, всё равно придётся применять другие методы тоже. Потому что будет много совпадений либо строка будет возвращаться с лишними символами

Comment: Всё получится...

Answer (score 0):

Выбирай:

```js
var s = "этот текст мне нужен / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст / текст /"

console.log(">>>" + s.match(/^[^/]*/)[0] + "<<<")
console.log(">>>" + s.match(/^([^/]*?)\s*\//)[1] + "<<<")
console.log(">>>" + s.match(/^([^/]*?)(?=\s*\/)/)[0] + "<<<")
```