# Помощь с регуляркой в js

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть текст

```
import __x_title___ from './ __x_title___'

new __x_title___()
```

и моя регулярка `/__x_(.*)___/g`

я хочу чтобы выбирало `__x_title___`, но выбирает `__x_title___ from './ __x_title___`

помогите сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте регулярку ленивой `/__x_(.*?)___/g`

Comment: Это и так все знают. Пожалуйста, не отвечайте на однотипные вопросы, ответ на который очевиден, для этого существует система дубликатов. Просто голосуйте за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: Видимо не все, тут 90% вопросов однотипные

Comment: Жадные/нежадные квантификаторы - известная проблема, её решение уже [неоднократно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) обсуждалась на этом сайте. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359258/) дан конкретный и ясный ответ, и нет смысла перепечатывать его раз за разом, как мантру, "используй ленивый квантификатор".